# Compiler Generated GetHashCode()

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, gethashcode, auto-generate

I'm working on writing a compiler for a language running on .net and one of the things I would like it to do is to automatically generate the GetHashCode method, but I have several questions:

- Is this possible, does the compiler know enough about the type(s) involved to do a reasonable job implementing the method?
- Should I do this for value types, reference types, or both?
- What is a reasonable GetHashCode algorithm for the compiler to generate which includes support for null properties and so forth?
- Has this been done in another language/compiler that I can look at?
- If this isn't possible or is a really bad idea, why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at what the C# compiler does for anonymous types. Basically it's the same sort of hash as I'd write myself:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 17;
    hash = 31 * hash + field1.GetHashCode();
    hash = 31 * hash + field2.GetHashCode();
    // etc
    return hash;
}
```

(You need some nullity checking as well, of course.)

I think it's a good idea to do this (and equality override) for immutable types, but generally *not* for mutable types. Value types should almost always be immutable anyway - reference types can go either way. Does your language have any built-in notion of immutability? Of course, this will go wrong if your type is "shallow immutable" but contains mutable types which override `GetHashCode` to indicate the *current* state of the object. Such types would generally be painful anyway.

In general though, I think it's reasonable in many cases to autogenerate equality and hash codes - indeed, I'd like this to be part of C# 5 for named types too: I want an easy way of *naming* types which otherwise have the same features as anonymous types.

Comment: The language doesn't have built-in immutability, picture a c#-3-like language. Would nullity checking just be, if null don't call GetHashCode or is there more to it?

Comment: @wawa: That's pretty much it. Use some constant (e.g. 0) for fields that have a null value.